# Enabled UIBarButtonSystemItemSave not blue on iOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4, ios7

I have this problem with a `UIBarButtonItem` of type `UIBarButtonSystemItemSave`. On the app I'm working on, which I test on compatibility mode from xCode 4 on an iPad that has iOS 7, the colour of the `UIBarButtonItem` of type `UIBarButtonSystemItemSave` is not blue as it should. 
But if I change the type to `UIBarButtonSystemItemDone`, the button looks normal("Done" button with blue as background colour).
Did anyone had this problem on their apps while testing their compatibility with iOS 7?